# copying and pasting values to the next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Excel files which i will open automatically. I would like to copy the values of the opened Excel files and paste it to the next empty row in my master file.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I suggest that you switch on the Macro record function in Excel, and record your actions. From there, you should be able to figure out what you need to use

Comment: the amount of rows are variable so i cant record a macro, which works only with specific row numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the last empty row in your master file you can use the below command.

```
LastRow = MasterFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(XlDown).Row + 1
```

This command is the same as going to cell A1 and pressing Ctrl + Down on your keyboard, only in memory.

From here you should be able to copy the data from your source workbook and paste it in the LastRow in your master file.